Couple with the most grandchildren to win a house
There's a nice, comedic, old movie in which a house is built in a small town and is promised to the resident couple with the most grandchildren. I can't remember the name of it or the names of the actors but in the end the nice old man who had eloped with a sweet older woman came back and, with more grandchildren between them, won the house, over the arrogant woman who thought she had it in the bag.
It has quite a few famous actors and actresses who have appeared in many movies of that time (maybe 30's/40's, not sure).
Which movie is this?

Edit:
Since first asking this question i have remembered more of the movie, yet still the name and actors elude me.
Right at the start of the movie a young boy catches a tadpole in a jar and takes it with him to the town meeting where they announced the competition. The jar is leaking and, upon noticing, the nice old man pours his glass of water into the jar
The young girl protagonist is in love with a young cobbler but they are too poor to get married and get a house, so they would eat lunch together at the house being built, make-believing it was theirs and they were getting home from a long days' work.
The husbands of the two main rival grandmothers would hang out in their adjoining back sheds drinking with each other over their secret window and would pack up every time they heard the screech of the train as it sounded like the women calling.
The rival women went to the house one day as it was being built. The workers were installing the sink and the two women started fighting over how high, saying it needed to be an inch higher/lower, and grabbed the sink, trying to put it at their respective level, causing it to drop and break.
Early on, the nice old man's wife picked some mushrooms and cooked and ate them, not realising they were in fact poisonous toadstools, her death therefore disqualified him from the contest and he drifted out of the movie. However on announcement day for the contest winner, he came back with a dear old lady who had also left the village. They had caught up with each other, married, and returned. Thus, as they had more grandchildren between them, they won the house, which they gave as a wedding gift to the young couple I mentioned earlier.
I may be wrong, but I have a strong feeling the nice old man could be Alastair Sim, however I couldn't seem to see the movie listed in his Wikipedia filmography.
I hope this helps anyone who may know which movie it is, as its a great old movie I haven't seen in a long time and would really love my wife to see, but I just can't remember it.

Children Galore from 1955 has a similar plot: a contest where a cottage is won by the family with the most grandchildren. It also contains a scene where a woman consumes poisonous mushrooms.
